# How to style a CSS buttons to show correctly in different versions of IE11?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 buttons, they display fine on Chrome, Edge, Firefox... but not on IE. I have now put in another style specifically for IE11 using

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
}
```

and have aligned the buttons, they display ok in later versions of IE11 e.g. version 11.1... but a lower version for instance 11.0... they are misaligned. Is it possible to correct/target the alignment at browser sub version level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional comment in HTML to load different CSS file but i don't know if works with subversion.

```
<!--[if IE 11 ]>
  <link href="iecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: With the media query that I use, I have got it working in later version of IE11 but not the lower ones which is what I need!

Comment: Not very elegant but i think the only is to use js browser sniffer to identify the browser version and apply specific CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go as well, I believe it may only be an issue in 1 particular version of IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following media query and put css you want show in only IE browser.

```css
/* only ie7, ie9, ie10, ie11 */
@media screen\0 {
css writing here for IE.........
}
```

Comment: With the media query that I use, I have got it working in later version of IE11 but not the lower ones, I am not too fussed about IE10 and below though it will be a bonus. With the @media screen\0 {} would that support all differnet sub versions of IE?

Comment: Yes, it's a <div> tag that encloses the <button>.

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, would you happen to know if there is a solution?